# Ruby - Directly send superclass a message

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I want to send a specific message to a superclass (see example). This is really easy with prototype based inheritance (since I can just send the message to my prototype), but I'm struggling to do this in Ruby.

Below is a simplified example of what I'd like to do

```
class BaseService
  def say_hello
    puts "hello"
  end
end

class SpecificService < BaseService
  def say_hello
    puts "hey you!"
    super
  end

  def say_hello_and_goodbye
    # send superclass the :say_hello message
    #
    # Couldn't find any references to superclass in docs,
    # so I make one up to show what I'd like to do.
    #
    # super.say_hello doesn't work either because super
    # looks up the superclass method :say_hello_and_goodbye

    superclass.say_hello
    puts "goodbye"
  end
end

SpecificService.new.say_hello
=> "hey you!"
=> "hello"

SpecificService.new.say_hello_and_goodbye
=> undefined local variable or method `superclass'

# desired
=> "hello"
=> "goodbye"
```

This example is contrived, but it demonstrates my issue. Is there anyway I can pass a message directly to the base class ala prototype inheritance?

Comment: Do you want to send a message to the superclass as your title says or do you want to send a message to an instance of the superclass and have the method being executed in response to this message be not the one of the instance's class but of the instance's class's superclass as your code seems to suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `SpecificService` overrides the method you want to call on the parent, you need to save a handle to the original (parent's) method. Check out [alias_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-alias_method).

```
class SpecificService < BaseService
  alias_method :original_say_hello, :say_hello

  def say_hello
    puts "hey you!"
    super
  end

  def say_hello_and_goodbye
    original_say_hello
    puts "goodbye"
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool, I had a feeling that alias had something to do with it. That clears things up, thanks!